# How to hide popup on click outside with animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

My point is:

1. If I click *OPEN* then should open the popup.
2. If click *BACK* then should close the popup
3. If I click outside popup then should close the popup.

**Note:** If I click anywhere inside popup when is open, then shouldn't close. Popup must closing only on outside click or *BACK* click.

How it currently work: If I click anywhere then popup is opening and closing.

So how to do this what I expect? I prepared JSFiddle and Code Snippet.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dcxte781/11/)

```js
$('#open-1').on('click touch', function() {
  $("#card-1").toggleClass("flip")
});

$(document).on('click touch', function(event) {
  if (!$(event.target).parents().addBack().is('#open-1')) {
    $("#card-1").toggleClass("flip");
  }
});

$('#open-1').on('click touch', function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
.panel {
  width: 45%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 14px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.est {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #333;
  background-color: transparent;
}

div {
  display: block;
}

#card-1 {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: 1;
  display: inline-block;
  perspective: 700px;
}

.flip .front {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.front {
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}

.front,
.back {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.ease {
  -webkit-transition: all .45s ease-out 0s;
  -moz-transition: all .45s ease-out 0s;
  -ms-transition: all .45s ease-out 0s;
  -o-transition: all .45s ease-out 0s;
  transition: all .45s ease-out 0s;
}

.open-1,
.open-2,
.open-3,
.open-4,
.open-5 {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 50px;
}

.back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  background-color: #ddd;
  display: table;
  z-index: 2;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 23px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  height: 320px;
}

.info {
  color: #333;
  font-size: 20px;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.flip .back {
    transform: rotateY(360deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="panel e-b est">   <div class="wrapper">
    <div id="card-1">
      <div class="front ease">
        <a href="javascript:void" class="open-1" id="open-1">open</a>
        <p>
          test content
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="back ease">
        <div class="back-info">
          <div class="info">
            test content
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="social-bar"><a href="javascript:void" class="open-1">Back</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>   </div> </div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dcxte781/11/)

Comment: Please change  `<a href="javascript:void" class="open-1">` to `<a href="#" class="open-1">` and add  e.preventDefault(); to `$('#open-1').on('click touch', function(e) { e.preventDefault();
  $("#card-1").toggleClass("flip")
});`

Comment: @mplungjan It's not readable for me. Could you add this as an anwser?

Comment: It is not an answer. But javascript:void gives error. At least use javascript:void(0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).on('click touch', function(event) {
  if (!$(event.target).parents().addBack().is('#open-1')) {
    $("#card-1").toggleClass("flip");
  }
});
```

You are `toggle()`ing the class here, instead use `removeClass()`:

```
$(document).on('click touch', function(event) {
  if (!$(event.target).parents().addBack().is('#open-1')) {
    $("#card-1").removeClass("flip");
  }
});
```

Then select the flipped div instead of the front one to stop toggling when the user clicks on the flipped div

```
$('.back.ease').on('click touch', function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Then add a class (for example `close-1`) to the `back` button:

`<a href="#" class="open-1 close-1">Back</a>`

And then add a function to remove the `flip` class upon clicking it

```
$('.close-1').on('click touch', function() {
    $("#card-1").removeClass("flip");
});
```

Comment: Alright, but now If I click anywhere inside popup then is closing.

Comment: @HubertFurka Updated my answer.

Comment: Popup is not closing on click inside, but now BACK text won't work.

Comment: @HubertFurka Updated once again, make sure to accept the answer if it helped. :)

Comment: Great. <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="open-1 close-1">Back</a> is better for me. Thank you for help.